# my program is not printing the expected output

Tags: java, stack

Here is the assignment I was given:

> Write a program which asks the user to enter an integer and then outputs the digits of that integer one by one.  For example, if the user inputs 2017 the program should output "Your digits are 2, 0, 1, and 7."  Use a stack to do this.

I have implemented my algorithm to accomplish this task, however, whenever I print the result returned from `extract_Digits_Stack` method the output is blank i.e there is nothing printed out to the console. anyone know why this is the case?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Extract_Digits 
{
  //main method
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter an integer : ");
    String inputString = scanner.nextLine();

    if (inputString == null || inputString.length() == 0) 
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the valid integer :");
      return;
    }
    String digits = extract_Digits_Stack(inputString);
    System.out.printf(digits);
  }
  private static String extract_Digits_Stack(String inputString) 
   {
     String[] arrString = inputString.split("");
     Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
     for(String input : arrString) 
     {
            stack.push(input);
     }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use your debugger. Add more details about the problem. As is, your question reads a lot like "fix my homework for me". Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Just initializing `StringBuilder` and returning it, without giving it any value?

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
return builder.toString();
```

This is returning an empty string.

Comment: Additionally the return type of `extract_Digits_Stack` doesn't make any sense. Disregarding the problem you point out it looks like OP is separating the integers out properly but then would just put them back together again (returning the original string). Perhaps a list or an array would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few mistakes/incomplete implementations within your code.

1. considering that a `Stack` is a last-in-first-out data structure it would make sense to reverse the parameter `inputString` prior to pushing it onto the `Stack`.  i.e if the user inputs `2017`, we will reverse it to `7102`, then `push()` it to the `Stack`.

Example:

```
2  // the forth item pushed to the stack <--- top of stack
0  // the third item pushed to the stack
1  // the second item pushed to the stack
7 // the first item pushed to the stack  <--- bottom of stack
```

so when we perform the `Pop()` operation the result will be `2017` because:

```
2 is popped off the stack // append to StringBuilder (2)
0 is popped off the stack // append to StringBuilder (20)
1 is popped off the stack // append to StringBuilder (201)
7 is popped off the stack // append to StringBuilder (2017)
```

Now going on to the implementation:

change this:

```
String[] arrString = inputString.split("");
```

to this:

```
String[] arrString = new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString().split("");
```

2. you're returning an empty `StringBuilder`, so let's make it do some useful work.

Example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("your digits are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
     if(i == inputString.length()-1) builder.append(" and ");
     builder.append(stack.pop());
     if(i < inputString.length()-2) builder.append(",");
}
return builder.toString();
```

Sample output:

```
Enter an integer : 2017
your digits are: 2,0,1 and 7
```

**note** - usually you should use [`Stack#empty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#empty()) method to determine whether there are still elements left in the `Stack` or not.The only reason I've used a `for` loop here is just to organise the output while performing `pop()` operation on the elements. There are other ways to achieve the same outcome of course.

full method implementation:

```
private static String extract_Digits_Stack(String inputString)
{
        String[] arrString = new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString().split("");
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

        for(String input : arrString)
        {
            stack.push(input);
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("your digits are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            if(i == inputString.length()-1) builder.append(" and ");
            builder.append(stack.pop());
            if(i < inputString.length()-2) builder.append(",");
        }
        return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding anything to your `StringBuilder` so of course when printing it out you'll get no output. What you should do after creating your stack and storing each character from the input into it is to pop each character from the stack one at a time to build your output message. However, a problem with this is the order in which you're storing characters into the stack. You're storing chars from the start of the input until the end. You should instead store chars from the end of the input until the start like so,

```
String[] arrString = inputString.split("");
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
for(int i = arrString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    stack.push(arrString[i]);
}
return stack;
```

So that the stack now looks like this when entering 2017

```
2 <-top of stack
0
1
7 <-bottom of stack
```

Also, like others have said your method should really return a `Stack<String>` in order for the assignment prompt to make much sense. Now in the main, you can manipulate this stack to get your output.

```
Stack<String> digits = extract_Digits_Stack(inputString);
System.out.print("Your digits are ");
while(!digits.empty()){
    String digit = digits.pop();
    System.out.print(digit + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After of use `push` to pushes an item onto the top of this stack you should use `pop` to remove the element at the top of this stack and return this value, those values you can add to `StringBuilder` using `append`.

```
private static String extract_Digits_Stack(String inputString) {
    //To print in the same order as it is entered
    //String[] arrString = new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString().split("");
    String[] arrString = inputString.split("");
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    for (String input : arrString) {
        stack.push(input);
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("The digits are: ");
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        builder.append(stack.pop() + ","); // Here append the elements
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This will print the elements separated by comma:

```
The digits are: 7,1,0,2,
```